# regex birthday validation

Tags: php, regex, validation, date

I have a regex which validate birthday:

```
if(!preg_match('/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- .\/](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- .\/](19|20)?[0-9]{2}$/', $_POST['bday'])
{
    echo 'enter your birthdate in a valid format. mm/dd/yyy';
}
```

which is:

**correct month**

*leap year date is not accurate*

*february accepts day 30 & 31*

*and the year 20 accepts greater than 2013*

I only done correct with months how can I do more accurate birthday validation? or there is any alternate way to validate birthday?

my desired output is:

**validate leap year date on month of february**

**year must not greater than 2010**

OUTPUT:

`02/14/2010`

I'm just quite new on regex kindly help?

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Regex is for pattern matching, not something as complex as date validation. Assuming you came up with an expression for what you want, it would be incredibly complicated and inefficient. Just look into the PHP date/time functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regex isn't well-suited for parsing dates. PHP already has built-in functions and classes to do this and you should use that instead. Here's how this can be done using PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) class (function by [Glavić](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67332/), from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205])):

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'm/d/Y')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date && $d->format('Y') <= 2010;
}
```

For example:

```
var_dump(validateDate('02/14/2010')); // bool(true)
var_dump(validateDate('02/14/2011')); // bool(false)
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/69081)

Comment: What if year shouldn't be greater than now?

Comment: @Halfacht Change `$d->format('Y') <= 2010` to `$d->format('Y') <= date('Y')`.