# sequelize birthday validate

Tags: validation, sequelize.js

I want add validate in my user model birthday attribute. this my code

```
 email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true,
        notEmpty: true
      }
    },
    birthday: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE(50),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
      validate: {
        isDate: true,
        notEmpty: true,
        }
      },
```

How can I add validate to my birthday ? I want to validate for birthday, User cannot enter future date of birth and user cannot be more than 120 years old. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regex birthday validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027821/regex-birthday-validation)

Comment: I don't want use regex for birthday

Comment: Just gonna point out that Jeanne Calment made it to 122 years old...

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize allows you to write custom validators:

```js
sequelize.define('user', {
  birthday: {
    validate: {
      isValidDateOfBirth(value) {
        const now = new Date();
        const minDateOfBirth = // calculate `now` - 120 years using a date & time library
    
        if (value < now) {
          throw new Error('Date of birth must not be in the future')
        }

        if (value < minDateOfBirth) {
          throw new Error('User can not be older than 120 years')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Small note: I would probably call the field `date_of_birth` and not `birthday` in the database

References: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/validations-and-constraints/

Answer (score 0):

it's works

```
  validate: {
    isDate: true,
    notEmpty: true,
    isNotFuture(value) {
      
      if (new Date(value) > new Date()) {
        throw new Error('Users not be born in the future.');
      }
    },
    isNotTooOld(value) {
      const currentDate = new Date();
      const maxAgeDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() - 120, currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate());
      

      if (new Date(value) < maxAgeDate) {
        throw new Error('Users not be older than 120 years.');
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**